# Display avatar edit view after clicking on the link in home view in the same Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I would like to have **avatar edit** in the same route as **home table**, switched on 'avatarEditToogle'. I would use ternary operator in my home component

`{{avatarEditToogle} : <AvatarEdit/> ? ... some logic to show default view}`
If avatarEditToogle then show AvatarEdit, else show table in my **home** component.
The problem how to pass the information from Link to the props. I have found solution.

```js
 <Link to={{pathname:'/',
               state: {
                     avatarEditToogle: true
               }
          }}
```

The problem is that whenever I click on the link the avatarEditToogle is true,
but in the home component before clicking link (avatar icon) is **props.location.state.avatarEditToogle** **undefined**. I would like to preset this props in some way to false, to not display AvatarEdit before clicking on the link.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem? After all, a `false` will `undefined` and you can use `undefined` value instead `boolean`

```
{!!avatarEditToogle ? <AvatarEdit/> : ... some logic to show default view}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your route is not gonna change, I guess it's not a good idea to use `Link` after all. you can use `useState` and save toggle value (true or false) inside it and whenever you click on toggle button, just change it's state:

```
const [showEdit, setShowEdit] = useSate(false);
...
...
<button onClick={() => setShowEdit(true)}>Edit Avatar</button>
{showEdit && <AvatarEdit/>}
```